# How to limit width of WPF Comboxes in a Grid Column to width of the widest Label in that column?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 2 columns which both have 2 combobox and 2 labels in a Grid column. Now depending on language either of the Labels can be the widest. I want all controls to be same width with the widest Label. The combobox texts are too wide to be shown entirely. How this is done?

Simplified example code:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Content="{DynamicResource LineAndTextColor}" Name="LineAndTextColorLabel"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
<Label Content="{DynamicResource Linetype}" Name="LineTypeLabel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding LineTypes}"/>
<Label Content="{DynamicResource FillColor}" Name="FillColorLabel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
<Label Content="{DynamicResource Linesize}" Name="LineWidthLabel"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding LineWidths}" />
```

Additional explanation:

I want all Comboboxes WITHIN a column to be same width with the widest Label of THAT column. so for both columns, the widest Label of THAT column determines the width of Comboboxes of THAT column. I need to restrict Combobox widths because they have very long strings.

Answer (score 0):

labels in each column are stretched so they have equal width. to restrict comboboxes to the same width add maxWidth setting for ech of them:

for comboboxes in the left column:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=FillColorLabel}"
```

Comment: but how does it know i want comboxes to be width of widest label? Widest label can be 'Line width' and Combobox can have 'This is very long color name'

Comment: in addition i don't want both columns to be equal width. i need to save space and width of widest Label in column is all I care

Comment: no it's not contradiction. i want all controls WITHIN a column to be same width with the widest Label of that column. so for both column, the widest Label of THAT column determines the width of Comboboxes of THAT column. I need to restrict Combobox widths because they have very long strings.

Comment: This is Ok, but I don't know which Label is the widest. I have 10 languages and maybe after month I have 11. I can do this with multibinding and converter that calculated the max of Labels, but I thought there was easier way.

Comment: You are right. I really can't ask these questions properly ever no matter how much I try.

Comment: In addition in reality I have 10 comboboxes and 10 labels

Comment: "labels in each column are stretched so they have equal width". doesn't matter which one to use in the column

Comment: this is also not working. I guess it changes label's actualwidth when combobox selection is changed to more wide element -> all are changed as wide as widest. as always in WPF, nothing really can be done even though "everything is possible". In reality you need to specify exact widths / heights to get sensible UI. this of course is no longer sensible when localization comes into play.